# How does "clickshaming" affect user experience?

Tags: buttons, popup, conversion, advertisement, sales-techniques

[image]

As you can see in the bottom of the image, the button (or link) to cancel the popup is labeled "No thanks, I'd rather not hire the best."

I can see why some websites do that, because users may feel bad if they click on something such as, "No thanks, I don't care about my skin", "Nah, I hate coupons", or something like that, so they'll want to click on the call-to-action button instead.

But do these actually work? Have these increased those websites' conversion rates?

Comment: It wouldn't stop me clicking on the "No thanks", but it might stop me dealing with a company that used such phrases.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A solid question, but I don't know how easy it will be to get raw numbers on this, or if they'll apply to your specific situation. It's important from an early stage to establish a way to split test new features like this so you can get realtime statistics for your own use case.

Keep in mind, the answer to this question is heavily influenced not only by the pop-up, but by the pop-ups context.

For example, when and why is the pop-up triggered?

- When trying to access advanced features only available to members?
- As soon as the page loads?
- After a certain scroll depth or a delayed time?
- When trying to close the page's tab or navigate away?

In summary, this question is more complex than "How does A correlate with B?" There are additional factors that require consideration. Also, given your specific industry, desired call to action, and overlay design, you may see very different results. Employing split testing will help you tweak and determine if your feature brings about the results you want.

Comment: I think the OP is more concerned about the messaging rather than the popup itself

Comment: You're likely right. To really quantify the impact of the messaging you would need to employ similar techniques: split test identical pop-ups where only the messaging is changed. I'd be curious to see if there's any published data on this, but it would be hard to argue that it holds in all contexts/situations.

Answer (score 1):

I have done a test on different accept/decline messaging using this very tactic.

We found that the 'I'd rather not benefit' type messaging actually had an overall detrimental effect or increased exit rates.

Due the negative wording on a negative button (decline a service for example) it caused the users to not want to click on anything on the page and ended up exiting the site completely which also had a knock-on effect of reducing returning visitors.

I would definitely suggest **testing the different type of wording** used here and see which performs the best for you, different audiences will react differently to this.

Personally I don't agree with this style of wording as it puts the user at unease and it's not intuitive to click on something that has a negative effect.